# Refine trait generic parameter

Tags: rust

Given this simplified code (which doesn't compile), how I can inform the compiler that, that in the `impl` I only wish `fn execute` to allow cases where `Model::Parameters == P`?

```
trait Model {
    type Parameters;
    fn run(&self, p: &Self::Parameters) -> f64;
}

trait Analysis {
    fn execute<M: Model>(&self, model: M) -> (M::Parameters, f64);
}

pub struct Data<P>{
    pub value: P, 
}

impl<P> Analysis for Data<P> {
    fn execute<M: Model>(&self, model: M) -> (M::Parameters, f64) {
        let p = self.value;
        (p, model.run(&p))
    }
}
```

I tried a `where` clause:

```
fn execute<M>(&self, model: M) -> (M::Parameters, f64) 
where M: Model<Parameters = P> {
    let p = self.value;
    (p, model.run(&p))
}
```

but the compiler rejects it as that deviates from the declaration in the `Analysis` trait, which knows nothing about P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add bounds to a trait method, because that would break the guarantee of Rust's trait system, that generic code will be usable in every case where its bounds are met — “no post-monomorphization errors”. You *can* add arbitrary bounds to a trait *implementation*, but that doesn't help here since `P` only appears in relation to `M` which is not a parameter or associated type of the *trait*, only its method. The trait's current signature is forcing every implementation to work for all possible `Model`s.

If you want to allow an `Analysis` to only work for certain kinds of `Parameters`, then you have to put that in the trait. One simple possibility is that `Analysis` should have an associated type like `Model` does, but I'm guessing that you would have thought about it already. Another possibility is to give `Analysis` a type parameter, which means that each implementation can choose whether or not it works for different `Parameters`. This compiles:

```rust
trait Model {
    type Parameters;
    fn run(&self, p: &Self::Parameters) -> f64;
}

trait Analysis<P> {
    fn execute<M: Model<Parameters = P>>(&self, model: M) -> (P, f64);
}

pub struct Data<P> {
    pub value: P, 
}

impl<P: Clone> Analysis<P> for Data<P> {
    fn execute<M: Model<Parameters = P>>(&self, model: M) -> (P, f64) {
        let p = &self.value;
        (p.clone(), model.run(p))
    }
}

// can also write impl<P> Analysis<P> for AnalysisThatDoesntCare {}
```

(I also had to change the function body to clone `self.value`, since `execute` returns `P` by value.)

Or maybe the `Analysis` trait should include the `Model` instead, so the trait is generic but the function isn't:

```rust
trait Model {
    type Parameters;
    fn run(&self, p: &Self::Parameters) -> f64;
}

trait Analysis<M: Model> {
    fn execute(&self, model: M) -> (M::Parameters, f64);
}

pub struct Data<P> {
    pub value: P, 
}

impl<M, P> Analysis<M> for Data<P>
where
    M: Model<Parameters = P>,
    P: Clone,
{
    fn execute(&self, model: M) -> (P, f64) {
        let p = &self.value;
        (p.clone(), model.run(p))
    }
}
```

This version allows the implementations to constrain what `Model`s they work with, not just their `Parameters` type, and it might be simpler when working with non-generic implementors of `Analysis`.

---

(P.S. Rust API style is to name traits after the *operations they enable*, not a description of the value, when that's practical. So, possibly your trait should be named `Analyze` with method `analyze()` (or `analyse()`) instead of `Analysis` and `execute()`.)